# ¿Por qué "chabacano" es denigrante en España, designa una lengua en Filipinas y se refiere a un albaricoque en México?

Tags: etimología, historia, españa, méxico

Mirando [un artículo sobre alimentación para niños](https://espanol.babycenter.com/a5700115/gu%C3%ADa-para-alimentar-a-tu-hijo-de-los-12-a-24-meses) me encontré con:

> Frutas: melón, papaya, **albaricoque (chabacano)** y toronja.

Resulta que en España usamos la palabra *albaricoque* para denominar a la [Prunus armeniaca](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_armeniaca):

> [image]

pero sin embargo la palabra *chabacano* la identificamos con algo muy diferente:

> [**chabacano, na**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8QuzCHF)
>   De or. inc.
>
> 1. adj. Grosero o de mal gusto.
> 2. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al chabacano (‖ lengua). Léxico chabacano.
> 3. m. Lengua criolla de base española y con la estructura gramatical de lenguas nativas, que se habla en Mindanao y otras islas filipinas.
> 4. m. Méx. albaricoque.

Como vemos, el DLE ya indica que en México esta palabra designa al albaricoque y el DAMER amplia un poco la información con:

> [**chabacano**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=chabacano)
>
> I.    1.  Mx, Cu, RD, Ar; PR, juv. **chabacán**.
>
> II.   1.  m. Mx. Albaricoque, fruto.

Donde la palabra *chabacán* a su vez viene definida como:

> [**chabacán**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=chabac%C3%A1n).
>
> I.    1.  sust/adj. Mx, Gu, Ho, ES, Ni, Pa, RD, Bo, Ur; Ar, p.u. Hombre grosero y de mal gusto. (chabacano).

Con todo esto quiero decir que me resulta bastante interesante que la palabra *chabacano* no tenga origen conocido pero que a la vez designe tres elementos tan distintos. ¿Tienen alguna relación?

Comment: Me ha costado mucho etiquetar, habría puesto también [tag:comida], [tag:filipinas], [tag:sustantivos], [tag:adjetivos] y alguna más. Si quieres, reetiqueta.

Comment: Por regionalismos ! 
En México cajeta es un dulce hecho a base de leche de cabra  
Pero que no se le ocurra decirle a alguien en argentina que su cajeta esta buena. cuales son las causas de estos regionalismos... ah pues por eso esto es un comentario y no una respuesta :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Evolución de significados

Las primeras entradas diccionarias de *chavacano* esclarecen un poco los orígenes:

> **CHAVACANO.** Deste termino vſan enel Reyno de Toledo, y a vnas ciruela, que por otro nombre dizen porcales, o harta puercos, las llaman chauacanas, y chauacano al hombre groſſero, vulgar e impertinẽte, del nõmbre Griego ΚαναλΘ, fatuus : la ipſylon pronunciamos noſotros como v. pero por mas cierto tengo ſer nombre Hebreo.
>
> - 1611 COVARRUBIAS

> **Chabacana** se llaman en Andaluzía a la mala fruta, y de aí por cosa baladí y mala; del Gr. que dice Sabacós a lo podrido ranzioso y azedo, y lleno de queresas.
>
> - 1611 ROSAL

> **Chavácano,** m. Homme groſſier.
>   **Ciruelas chavacanas,** f. *Ce ſont certaines prunes à Tolede, qu'on apelle autrement* porceales,  harta puercos, *prunes à nourrir les cochons.*
>
> - 1705 SOBRINO

Así que, parece que primeramente tenía la definición de una fruta mala o pútrida, y de allí las dos definiciones de:

1. una especie de fruta
2. algo grosero en general

> *ciruela > [ciruela porcal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TgQCE1V) > ciruela chavacana > chavacana*

Es más fácil ver como, de allí, una palabra que significa *"vulgar", "común", "de baja calidad"* la aplicaría una gente colonialista a una lengua criolla para distinguirla de su propia lengua. Puedes ver esto en sus sinónimos de esa época: [*"lenguaje de la calle", "lenguaje de parian",  "lenguaje de cocina"*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criollo_chabacano#Etimolog%C3%ADa).

Análoga es la palabra *patois* en francés para denominar las lenguas no prestigiosas (ej. occitano, etc).

---

## Primeros usos registrados

<sup>Parece que más temprano, *chabacana* también significó fruta desabrida:</sup>

> <sup>Las que llaman ciruelas son verdaderamente fruta de arboles... Otras hay grandes, y de color escura y de mucha carne; **pero es comida gruesa y de poco gusto, que son como chabacanas.** Estas tienen dos o tres hosezuelos pequeños en cada una.</sup>
>
> - <sup>[*Historia natural y moral de las Indias*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BMFLkCEiJaIC&pg=PA235&lpg=PA235&dq=chabacanas), José de Acosta (1590)</sup>

<sup>Y Diego Sánchez de Badajoz en 1554, con multiples significaciones:</sup>

> <sup>Sería injusto quien, fijándose únicamente en composiciones de 
>   la ínfima laya de los Disparates trobados, confundiese á Juan del 
>   Enzina en el grupo de los copleros chabacanos y adocenados.</sup>
>
> - <sup>[*HISTORIA DE LA POESÍA CASTELLANA*](https://archive.org/stream/obrascompletas06men/obrascompletas06men_djvu.txt)</sup>

> <sup>No hay barbero aquí presente
>
>   Yo con este chabacano.
>
>   Ay peidoneos Dios, hermano.</sup>
>   <sup>...</sup>
>   <sup>Dejaréis el chabacano.
>
>   Pablo. Espera.
>
>   Fraile. Vén acá, hermano,</sup>
>   <sup>...</sup>
>   <sup>**Nota al pie de página**:</sup>
>   <sup>Sin duda se dispone á afeitar al
>   fraile con un instrumento que 
>   llama chabacano, quizas por 
>   su forma grosera , pues los pas- 
>   tores á veces de un hierro meti- 
>   do en un palo hacen cuchillo. 
>   Que es instrumento cortante, se 
>   deduce también de la pág. 37.</sup>
>
> - <sup>[*Recopilacion en metro del Bachiller Diego Sanchez de Badajoz*](https://archive.org/stream/recopilacionenm01sngoog/recopilacionenm01sngoog_djvu.txt)</sup>

Comment: Interesante uso de _pútrido_, pensé que no era correcto. En general solemos hablar de _podrido_.

Comment: @fedorqui cuándo hablo suelo usar muchos calcos de inglés de origen francés/latín (cf. [*putrid*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/putrid)), a veces tengo suerte y son palabras castellanas de verdad haha

Comment: Pues me tienes alucinado con la cantidad de veces que aciertas jajaja